# R: force reinstallation of package's dependencies

Tags: r

My system installation of R is controlled by administrators, who make changes upon request from multiple users without coordination.  This causes problems for me because some packages installed in my user library interact badly with upgraded packages in the system library.  This breaks cron jobs and I have to spend time maintaining it.

When running `install.packages` or an equivalent, is there a way to make R ignore system-installed packages, and install *all* transitive dependencies in my user library?  For example, I tried running `R_LIBS=/path/to/lib R` but the system install is still on `.libPaths()`, and dependencies of my package are still not installed in my user library.

Comment: Try both R_LIBS="" and R_LIBS_SITE=""  in ~/.Renviron

Answer (score 1):

Oh! It looks like [renv](https://github.com/rstudio/renv) is just what I want.